# react-native-video - multiple videos causing app crash

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-video

I have a feed which displays multiple videos in a `<FlatList/>`. Each video is hosted offsite on a uri. 
Each video in the feed is muted and paused and I am triggering the ones in viewport to play (usually no more than 3 at a time).

On iOS I started seeing the app crash with the error `Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue` in Xcode. I see memory spike slightly (it goes from ~120MB to ~150MB, holds for a few seconds then the app crashes). 
Because of this I tried keeping the videos all paused but the same thing happens. 
When I switch out the `<Video/>` for a `<FastImage/>` preview the crash stops.

Example of a video component:

```
<Video
  source={{ uri: props.uri }} 
  repeat={true}
  muted={true}
  volume={0.0}
  paused={props.paused}
  posterResizeMode="cover"
  resizeMode="cover"
  poster={props.thumbnail}
  style={props.style}
  ref={ref => {
    this.player = ref;
  }}
/>
```

Has anyone else experienced this error message/crash with `react-native-video`? 
Is there a way to get more info out of Xcode as to why this is happening?

Android seems to handle things for a little longer but also results in an eventual crash.

Some info:

- RN 0.59.10
- React 16.8.6
- react-native-video 5.1.0-alpha1 (this is so I can fix the pause video bug in earlier versions)

Comment: I have the same problem, did you make it work with video compression or some kind of memory optimisation ?

Comment: Same issue here. Have you found any solution ?

Comment: In the end I used the FlatList `onViewableItemsChanged` functionality to manage what was on screen and should be playing vs what was offscreen. In addition, I switched out any component off screen to a thumbnai image in order to reduce the number of `<Video />` component instances.

Comment: @scgough Can you please paste the above used solution